# creating a subscription form for individual objects

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, plugins

Currently I have a plugin on the site that utilizes wp favorites. I've modified the wording so it's a pull list instead of "favoriting"

A user clicks a button 'add to pull list' and it adds that item to their "wp favorites" Which I don't think I'm going to be able to modify this in the way I want.

What I really want to do is be able to add these to a separate page called "Your Pull List" for example. On that page it totals the costs of each item and there will be a subscription button which will utilize paypals subscription or a button to pick-up in store. Then once their done adding all of the comics they want they can subscribe and be charged the total amount of all items.

I don't even know where to begin in setting this up. Every plugin I've found for recurring is just membership stuff and won't work in my case, as i need the items to go to a separate page be talied from there for the paypal subscription button.

Then...what if the customer wants to add more items to their pull list or remove items? Will paypals subscription api update or is this something better to just let the shop owner manually charge per month rather than automate it?

Lastly, anyone who sets up a pull list will be added in the backend of the website where the admin can manage the pull lists, print out pull lists for each user, and be notified via email whenever an existing client modifies their pull list, or a new client signs up.

So my question is - is there a plugin out there that can handle this or "close" to handle it, that I could modify? Or is this a do it from scratch idea?